# Logo in website is not showing in IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, png

Shows in all browsers except IE. The image is a tranparent png.

music.thebc.co

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All versions of IE will not show the image.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not appreciate `width:auto`

Put a conditional if around the image to give IE 1 without the width

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Just to be clear:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<img height="100" id="logo" alt="The Brilliantly Creative Company Logo" src="http://www.music.thebc.co/images/bcco_logo.png"/>
-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<img width="auto" height="100" id="logo" alt="The Brilliantly Creative Company Logo" src="http://www.music.thebc.co/images/bcco_logo.png"/>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!  I never use auto width for images.  This is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AlphaImageLoader as suggested here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:140px; height:400; width:400;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
     src='image.png', sizingMethod='scale');" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 it looks like the image is placed correctly, but it just needs a higher z-index; try this CSS:

```
#logo {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Hi Owlvark.  z-index was one of the first things I thought about but it wasn't the issue.  Thanks though.